# Trouble copying a vector into a queue in c++

Tags: c++

I am working with a vector of around 400 float members and for my assignment I need to copy the vector into a queue. I never really understood the purpose of the queue and that has not made it easy. Here is what the function that I currently have....

```
template<typename T>
void vector_to_queue(std::queue<T> q, std::vector<T> v){
   for(vector<T>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++){
      q.push();
   }
}
```

This is as far as I've gotten, I am completely stumped and would appreciate any help that can be provided.

Comment: You have an iterator that points at the next element to push into the queue. So push it! Also, the function should take the queue by reference, so that the changes won’t be thrown away when the function returns.

Comment: _I never really understood the purpose of the queue_ Think of it as a place to park things that you want to process later.  FIFO means that you remove things from it, when you're ready to, in the order they went in.  One application might be when recording audio.  This typically arrives on a high priority thread, but you don't want to stall that thread for any reason so it just puts it into a queue and moves on.  A lower priority thread then reads from the queue, when able, writes the audio to disk.  Google 'leaky bucket', that should turn up some relevant hits.

Comment: @PaulSanders I was about to complain that Google represents a priority queue at least, but then realized thst you talk about "googling it"

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing nothing to the queue, this should work for you:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void vector_to_queue(std::queue<T>& q, const std::vector<T>& v){
   for(vector<T>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++){
      q.push(*it);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
template<typename T>
void vector_to_queue(std::queue<T> &q, const std::vector<T> &v) {
   for (const auto &elem : v) {
      q.emplace(elem);
   }
}
```

Or little fancy

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
void vector_to_queue(std::queue<T> &q, const std::vector<T> &v) {
   std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&q](const auto &elem){ q.emplace(elem); });
}
```